Update product attributes via REST API woocommerce
I am trying to import product attributes that I have stored in an external database into woocommerce.
I relate the product by sku and obtain the woocommerce product id.
I try to first see if the attributes and values ​​exist before creating them and then update the product.
I see that in Woocommerce > Attributes it does import the attributes and their values.
But it does not update the product or assign the corresponding attributes or values.
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\APIModel;
use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;
use WebSocket\Client as WebSocketClient;

require_once __DIR__ . '/../Helpers/helpers.php';

class APIController {
    private $apiModel;
    private $woocommerce;
    private $socketUrl = 'ws://localhost:3001';

    public function __construct($config) {
        $this->apiModel = new APIModel($config, 'bylonfive');

        $this->woocommerce = new Client(
            'https://testing.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.es',
            'ck_dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxc',
            'cs_fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxa',
            [
                'version' => 'wc/v3',
                'query_string_auth' => true
            ]
        );
    }

    public function showImportForm() {
        include __DIR__ . '/../Views/api/import_form.php';
    }

    public function importProducts() {
        $limit = $_POST['limit'] ?? 10;
        $products = $this->apiModel->getProducts($limit);

        $this->importAttributes($products);
        $this->updateProductAttributes($products);
    }

    private function importAttributes($products) {
        $client = new WebSocketClient($this->socketUrl);

        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $attributes = $this->extractAttributes($product['attributes']);

            foreach ($attributes as $name => $value) {
                $client->send(json_encode(['message' => "Importando atributo: {$name} con valor: {$value}"]));

                // Obtener o crear el atributo global
                $attribute_id = $this->getOrCreateAttribute($name);

                // Obtener o crear el término del atributo
                $term_id = $this->getOrCreateTerm($attribute_id, $value);
            }
        }

        $client->close();
    }

    private function extractAttributes($attributeString) {
        $attributes = [];
        $pairs = explode(';', $attributeString);
        foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
            $parts = explode(':', $pair);
            if (count($parts) == 2) {
                $attributes[trim($parts[0])] = trim($parts[1]);
            }
        }
        return $attributes;
    }

    private function getOrCreateAttribute($name) {
        $existing_attributes = $this->woocommerce->get('products/attributes');
        foreach ($existing_attributes as $attribute) {
            if (strcasecmp($attribute->name, $name) == 0) {
                return $attribute->id;
            }
        }

        $data = [
            'name' => $name,
            'slug' => sanitize_title($name),
            'type' => 'select',
            'order_by' => 'menu_order',
            'has_archives' => true
        ];
        $new_attribute = $this->woocommerce->post('products/attributes', $data);

        return $new_attribute->id;
    }

    private function getOrCreateTerm($attribute_id, $value) {
        $existing_terms = $this->woocommerce->get("products/attributes/{$attribute_id}/terms");
        foreach ($existing_terms as $term) {
            if (strcasecmp($term->name, $value) == 0) {
                return $term->id;
            }
        }

        $data = [
            'name' => $value,
            'slug' => sanitize_title($value)
        ];
        $new_term = $this->woocommerce->post("products/attributes/{$attribute_id}/terms", $data);

        return $new_term->id;
    }

    private function updateProductAttributes($products) {
        $client = new WebSocketClient($this->socketUrl);

        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $client->send(json_encode(['message' => "Obteniendo producto por SKU: {$product['sku']}"]));

            $response = $this->woocommerce->get('products', ['sku' => $product['sku']]);

            if (!empty($response)) {
                $product_id = $response[0]->id;
                $client->send(json_encode(['message' => "Producto encontrado: ID {$product_id}"]));

                $attributes = $this->extractAttributes($product['attributes']);
                $attributes_data = [];

                foreach ($attributes as $name => $value) {
                    $client->send(json_encode(['message' => "Obteniendo atributo: {$name} con valor: {$value}"]));

                    $attribute_id = $this->getOrCreateAttribute($name);

                    $term_id = $this->getOrCreateTerm($attribute_id, $value);

                    $attributes_data[] = [
                        'id' => $attribute_id,
                        'name' => $name,
                        'option' => $value,
                        'visible' => true,
                        'variation' => false
                    ];
                }

                $data = [
                    'attributes' => $attributes_data
                ];

                $client->send(json_encode(['message' => "Datos a enviar para SKU {$product['sku']}: " . json_encode($data)]));
                $updated_product = $this->woocommerce->put("products/{$product_id}", $data);
                $client->send(json_encode(['message' => "Producto actualizado: SKU {$product['sku']}"]));

                $updated_product_data = json_encode($updated_product->attributes);
                $client->send(json_encode(['message' => "Atributos actualizados para SKU {$product['sku']}: {$updated_product_data}"]));
            } else {
                $client->send(json_encode(['message' => "Producto no encontrado para el SKU: {$product['sku']}"]));
            }
        }

        $client->close();
    }
}

function sanitize_title($title) {
    $title = strtolower($title);
    $title = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\-]/', '-', $title);
    $title = preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $title);
    return trim($title, '-');
}



The attributes in the db look like this:
Color:Negro;Conectividad:Ethernet;Tecnologia de Impresion:Termica Monocromo;Tecnologia Termica:Directa;Tipo de Impresora:Tickets;
